# Why doesn't this line of code work properly?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here's the part of my code that's giving trouble:

```
    class_number = input("Before your score is saved ,are you in class 1, 2 or 3?")
    if class_number not in (1,2,3):
        sys.exit("That is not a valid class, unfortunately your score cannot be saved, please try again")
    else:
        filename = (class_number + "txt")
```

But when the program asks the user what class the user is, regardless of the input the program exits the system. This happens even if the user input *is* in (1,2,3).

Why isn't it working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python3, `input` just returns a string, so when you call it to get the `class_number` variable you're getting a string instead of an int. You need to explicitly declare it as an int

```
class_number = int(input("Which classes scores would you like to see? Press 1 for class 1, 2 for class 2 or 3 for class 3"))
```

Alternatively, it might be safer to check the result against strings (since you don't need to perform arithmetic on the result)

```
if class_number not in ('1', '2', '3'):
```

This is safer because the previous method could call `int()` on a string that cannot be turned into a number and that will throw an exception. For example if the user enters "three" that will raise an exception. You'll have no such trouble if you just use a string.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this ?

```
class_number = int(input("..."))
if class_number not in (1, 2 ,3):
    sys.exit("...")
```

`input` in Python 3 is equivalent to `raw_input` in Python 2. It returns a string. If you want to compare a string to an int, you must convert one of the two. You can also do the following :

```
class_number = input("...")
if class_number not in ("1", "2" ,"3"):
    sys.exit("...")
```